# What is the most efficient way to sync clients with server database

Tags: java, android, mysql, ios, database

I will develop a mobile application which can work both online and offline.

### Client

1. Client can see just data. They can't change anything in either server database or its database.
2. Each client has its database, like copy of server database. Because application has to work also offline. If internet is available, the app tries to update itself.

### Server

1. An admin can change database via admin client. There is just one database which serves to all clients when they are online.

My question is that how to do it. What is the most efficient way to achieve it? When an admin changes server database and a client wants to update, how should server provide a data which is between client revision to server last revision. For instance:

**Server**

- Revision 1
- Revision 2
- Revision 3
- Revision 4

**Client A**

- Revision 1
- Revision 2

**Client B**

- Revision 1

When Client A wants to update, it should get Revision 3-4, and when Client B wants to update, it should get Revision 2-3-4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a revision table(incremental IDs) in your database. Once the client gets online, at the start up, your app checks the max ID from server and compares it with client's revision ID. If the server's max ID is greater than client's, it updates the system based on the revision table on your server ( you can insert procedure names for revision updates into other columns so you can select procedure names during the checking process and then run these procedures for updates, or other columns may include descriptions )

Client's revision should not be greater than server's. If so, you should downgrade client's revision.

If there's a missing revision in the table, this is not a problem, your revision update procedure will not run for that version. 
if you're using sql stored procedures your client side updates will be like this: (client's version is R2 and server's is R6 and R5 is deleted by admin)

```
exec sp_revision_update R3
exec sp_revision_update R4
exec sp_revision_update R6
```

in this example R5 was deleted from the server and R6 **MUST** include fixes for previous revision because some clients may have R5 before it was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the "ID" for check it, so you receive the max id from a client and the server check if the client need to update, p.e. in your server your max. ID is 4 and the max. ID client is 2 (Client A) you update from 3 to last ID otherwise do anything.

Comment: Your solution works if admin doesn't delete anything. for example, server has r1, r2, r3, r4, client has been updated and it is same as server. But when admin removes r3, client will never get the r3 diff! Because you will provide max id.